# Saving file to server in ColdFusion

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion

After doing some research I feel this should work, however it is not saving the file to my Images directory.

```
    <cfform name="uploadImgForm" method="post" action="#CGI.PATH_INFO#?#CGI.QUERY_STRING#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="txtImg" type="file" />
    <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" />
</cfform>
<cfif isDefined("Form.txtImg")>
    <cffile action="upload"
        fileField = "txtImg"
        destination="/Images"
        accept="image/jpeg"
        nameconflict="makeunique">
</cfif>
```

I plan on doing some validation, but I would like to get this simple example working first.

I came across this later which is helpful when trying to rename a file before upload:
[Adobe link](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/07/renaming_files.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The destination has to be a full path, otherwise it gets sent to a directory relative to the temp directory of ColdFusion.

Try this:

```
<cfset destination = expandPath("Images") />

<cffile action="upload"
    fileField = "txtImg"
    destination="#destination#"
    accept="image/jpeg"
    nameconflict="makeunique">
```

Comment: that gave me an error which in turn told me what the physical path was. Got it working :)

Comment: +1 the whole temp directory thing always seemed like mystery meat to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any error messages at all?  Or, after posting, do you just get the form again?

Firstly, does the /Images directory exist under the default CF temp directory?

Secondly, try getting rid of the "accept" argument to the CFFILE, just in case your browser's sending an odd MIME type.

Comment: I just get the form again. I don't know what you mean by the def temp directory. I was under the assumption that  /Images would be a folder name Images in the root.

Comment: What OS are you on?  Windows, OSX, or Linux?

Comment: windows. I typed in some bogus path and I got this as a path its trying to use: C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\servers\coldfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\wwwroot-tmp.

Comment: Ah, I haven't touched windows in a while, and assumed that windows would require the path to start with a drive letter to be absolute, but you can start it with a "/" and it will still be absolute.

Comment: If you don't end the "destination" with a "/" (ie. /Images/) then, if the directory doesn't exist, its going to save your uploaded file as that NAME (ie, the uploaded image will be "c:\Images".  If the directory exists, then it will put that file into the directory with the original name.  If you end the dest with a "/", then if the directory doesn't exist, you'll get an error (which is more expected) instead of making a file with that name.  Perhaps this might have been what you were originally experiencing.