# Saving file to server in Coldfusion, storing In CF temp directory instead of specified destination

Tags: mysql, html, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm using Coldfusion 8 on an Ubuntu Linux server with Apache and MySQL. Any file uploaded get stored in the Coldfusion temp directory:
[/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/neotmp17260.tmp] I obviously want it to be stored in to /var/www/cfm3/images [which the value of #destination#. I have tried other solutions provided by this site but they tend to fork off to other solutions that have not solved my solution. Below is the an example of my code.

```
    <cfset destination = expandPath("images") />
<cfif not directoryExists(destination)>
    <cfdirectory action="create" directory="#destination#">
</cfif>
<cfloop from="1" to="#num_users#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>User #i# Photo Upload : 
        <cfif isDefined("#i#")>
            <cffile action="upload"
                    fileField="#i#"
                    accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png" 
                    destination="#destination#"
                    nameConflict="makeUnique"
                    mode = 777>
            <cfdump var="#upload#">
            <p>Thank you, your file has been uploaded.</p>
        </cfif>
        <input type="file" name="#i#" /><br />
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a hunch the problem lies within how you are creating the `destination` variable, assuming it is correct (even after a create), and then immediately passing it to CFFILE.

Refer to this similar question (and solution):

[Saving File to Server in ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949107/saving-file-to-server-in-coldfusion)

In this question linked above, the answerer notes that:

> The destination has to be a full path, otherwise it gets sent to a
>   directory *relative to the temp directory of Cold Fusion* [sic].

This is very similar behavior to what you are experiencing--you want the file in a specific folder, but rather than error out, it ultimately lands in the "temp" dir.

I'd get some trace/debugging info in your template, specifically surrounding the value of the destination variable, prior to it being fed to CFFILE. Something doesn't quite gel with your description, and it could very well be a faulty path, or perhaps permissions surrounding it.

Comment: That's a good point.  I always use GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath()) to find my relative path root - could be that is something he needs to switch to, to get a reliable base path.

Comment: I couldn't fix it from my current program, raged, and rewrote with your instructions, and VIOLA, it worked. So thanks by the way. :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error similar to "upload not defined"?  If so, change this line:

```
<cfdump var="#upload#">
```

To this:

```
<cfdump var="#cffile#">
```

If you aren't getting that error.... what output are you getting?

*edit*

Also, personally I wouldn't name your form fields as simple numbers.  Try changing to this:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#num_users#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>User #i# Photo Upload : 
        <cfif isDefined("user#i#")>
            <cffile action="upload"
                    fileField="user#i#"
                    accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png" 
                    destination="#destination#"
                    nameConflict="makeUnique"
                    mode = 777>
            <cfdump var="#cffile#">
            <p>Thank you, your file has been uploaded.</p>
        </cfif>
        <input type="file" name="user#i#" /><br />
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Note the "user" prefix before your field names.

Comment: Oh, I'm not getting really an error other than the file not uploading to the specified location. It instead is going to a random location "/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/neotmp17260.tmp"

Comment: As for my poor naming scheme this was because I was wanting to review those specific uploads dynamically, and that was the only way I could figure it out in ColdFusion.

Comment: No error at all?  Are you perhaps running this within some kind of error trap, which might prevent the error from being shown?

Comment: Do you have a <cferror> tag in either your Application.cf(m|c) or header.cfm?  Also, check to see if you have an onError function defined within your Application.cfc (if you are using Application.cfc).  These things (if present) may be suppressing the error (if there really is one).